# Send eth from one account to another using transfer() function

Tags: contract-development, transactions, ether, contract-debugging, ethereumjs

I am trying to write a smart contract that will send eth from one account to another account :

```
Contract Send {

 event Sent(address from, address to, uint amount );

 function send(address _receiver, uint _amount) public payable{
    _receiver.transfer(_amount);
    emit Sent(msg.sender, _receiver, _amount);
 }
}
```

Here, the amount is deducted from the sender's account but not being added to receivers account.
I want to use `transfer()` function for this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: by sender you mean the contract? The ether will be taken from the contract. So the sender should send an amount of ether equal to `amount` when calling the function send, or the contract should have `amount` ethers

Answer (score 3):

This contract works and there is no need to change it.

The user interacting with this contract must send Ether in the transaction in order to trigger a transfer to the `_receiver`. The Ether gets sent to the contract, and lives there prior to transfer from the contract to the `_receiver`.

I would suggest removing `_amount` and simply using `msg.value` to send the entire value that is sent in the transaction.

Additionally, this can be done with a simple transaction and does not decessarily need a smart contract.